# Would JSoup be my best option to turn a website into a native android application

Tags: java, android, web, jsoup

I would like to make an android application for a website. I would like the app to be more than just a web-view displaying the website, that would be pretty pointless. Has anyone done this before that wouldn't mind helping me out.

Comment: Do you own the Web site? If yes, why are you not reworking it to expose a clean Web service API for your mobile apps to use? If you do not own the Web site, does the site terms of service clearly allow you to do what you are proposing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you would like to do. I love using jsoup.

If it is an app that simply only scrapes and displays data of a webpage that would be the easiest route. If you have a login on that webpage it is already getting a bit more difficult but still quite easily doable.

In any case you will have to use some sort of html parser/scraper if you want to write an app for an existing webpage and in my opinion jsoup is one of the best and easiest to handle, because in many cases not the complete webpage has to be downloaded. It can check for specific tags, classes, names, elements on a webpage and only select the things needed

Have a look for yourself on jsoup.org